# Issue with returning value in php function

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new in programming and especially with php and MySQL. I have to create dynamic web site for homework. My problem is with the function below. I want it to return int value of tag by given tag name (string). But in my case the function returns every time '1'. Can anyone help  me to solve this problem, thanks.

```js
public function getTagIdByName(string $tagName) : int
    {
        $statement = self::$db->prepare("SELECT tags.id FROM tags WHERE tags.name = ? ");
        $statement->bind_param("s", $tagName);
        $result = $statement->execute();
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Using `mysqli` prepared statements, you'll need to `bind_result` to a variable before fetching. See the example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're returning the result of `execute()`, but that function doesn't actually give you your query result. You need to fetch results after making sure the execution was successful.

```
//don't forget to error-check before using query results
$statement->execute() or die($statement->error);
$result = $statement->get_result(); //retrieve results for processing

if(!$result->num_rows) return null;//if the id was not found in the DB    
else return $result->fetch_assoc()['id'];
```

Comment: He's using `mysqli`, not `PDO`.

Comment: Let me know when you fix your answer and I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @Barmar I made the change. How did you know that `mysqli` was used by the OP?

Comment: Because he's using `$statement->bind_param()`, not `$statement->bindParam()`.

Comment: BTW, you can only use `fetch_assoc()` with a prepared statement if you're using the MYSQLND driver. Otherwise you need to use `$statement->bind_result()`.

Comment: @Barmar didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve easily with

```
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();
return $data['id']; // you can change with which you want to return with field name
```

And whichever you can use your returned values.